# Do not leave the activity as long as the progress bar is visible

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a horizontal progress bar in my activity that appears when the user tries to upload a file to firebase I that when this progress bar is visible, the user can not exit the activity in which he is located. How can I do this?

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/post_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/new_post_image" />
```

Comment: This is not possible. Please, attach a code of the activity.

Comment: By exiting do you mean pressing back button? If yes then you can simply put a condition on Activity's  `onBackpressed` that if the progress bar is visible or not and then call it's super method accordingly.

Comment: can you show me how to do it please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it so that the user cannot have any interaction with the activity while the progress bar is visible then in your java code you can just get a reference to the progress bar and do the following:

```
progressbar.setCancelable(false)
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: the setCancelable method does not exist I have already tried it

Answer (score 0):

Call setCancelable(false) throw progressbar Object Like this..

// use this line 
progressbar.setCancelable(false)

Comment: the setCancelable method does not exist I have already tried it